# What's the difference between displayP3Red and red

Tags: swift, uicolor

In Swift I have found two ways to initialize an UIColor

```
UIColor(displayP3Red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)
UIColor(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)
```

Is there a difference between those two ways?

Comment: From their doc: "in the Display P3 color space." vs "(s)RGB colorspace". I'd tend to say that if you don't do "quality/advance", for Photos/Videos/Drawing kind in which case you should already know the difference between theses colorspaces, you shouldn't really notice the difference.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/712/ "Working with Wide Color" has all the details.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is my summary from the following resource

> https://creativepro.com/how-do-p3-displays-affect-your-workflow/

UIColor(red...) is in the sRGB colorspace which can display a specific gamut (or range) of colors. Most displays, printers, other devices can display colors in this color space.

There are other colorspaces, such as the Adobe RBG color space, or Apple's P3 color space that can display a wider range of colors. A device that can display these colors are known as *wide gamut* displays.

The below image compares the adobe, p3, and srgb color spaces.
[image: Image Comparing Adobe, P3 and sRGB colorspaces] (Picture taken from https://creativepro.com/how-do-p3-displays-affect-your-workflow/)

Answer (score 0):

Nice recent article from Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=5cda5ipr

**TL;DR
Apple says of Display P3 Colors:**
"They’ll look richer and more vibrant on any device with a wide color gamut display.
You can find wide color gamut Retina displays on most Macs, as well as iPhone, iPad, and Apple Watch. They bring more true-to-life colors and deep hues to the screen, not only making for excellent image and video viewing but also heightening people’s everyday app experience.
Use Display P3 assets in your app to amplify important elements of your interface: the colors of a VU meter in an audio app, for instance, or the redline in a rev counter inside your racing game."